# Requirejs not processing call in errback on failed module load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have a require call (angular app):

```
require(['app','angular','jquery']
  , function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
    });
```

There is a path in my require config file that is getting a 404 error, so my onError handler is as so:

```
require.onError =          
    function(modError) {           //on error
    var failedModule = modError.requireModules && modError.requireModules[0];
    if (failedModule === 'testrender') {
        require.undef(failedModule); 

        delete configJSON.paths.testrender;     //remove testrender from paths
        require.config(configJSON);             //re-initialize the config

        require(['app','angular','jquery'], function() { });

    } 
};
```

I followed the instructions in the require documentation: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks,

however the require call is not being called that second time. Am i missing something? Please help!

Comment: This is just a guess, but it's possible requireJS prevents you from calling require inside of an onError handler; otherwise, you'd run the risk of a circular call. See what happens if you just wrap that require() inside of a setTimeout. Also, in your first block, you need to give local-names for 'app', 'angular', and 'jquery' (ie, `function(app, angular, $)`)

Comment: the require documentation has a wrapped call: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks....as for the local names, that's not the issue, it works fine without them...so frustrating!

Comment: Your URL seemed to get shortened, and I can't follow it. I searched the page for "onError =" and only found one result, and it doesn't wrap any other require() call.

Comment: requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks